# How to subclass django's generic CreateView with initial data?

Tags: django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to create a dialog which uses jquery's .load() function to slurp in a rendered django form. The .load function is passed the pk of the "alert" object. Also available in the class functions are things like `self.request.user` so I can pre-fill those fields, shown below in the Message model (models.py):

```python
class Message(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    alert = models.ForeignKey(Alert)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    message = models.TextField()
```

Subclassing django's CreateView makes it pretty easy to generate a context with an instance of the ModelForm (views.py):

```python
class MessageDialogView(CreateView):
    """ show html form fragment """
    model = Message
    template_name = "message.html"

    def get_initial(self):
        super(MessageDialogView, self).get_initial()
        alert = Alert.objects.get(pk=self.request.POST.get("alert_id"))
        user = self.request.user
        self.initial = {"alert":alert.id, "user":user.id, "message":"test"}
        return self.initial


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MessageDialogView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        context = self.get_context_data(form=form)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

The problem here is that `self.initial` does not get rendered with the form. I have insured that the form is indeed calling `get_initial` and the form instance has the proper initial data in `post`, but when the form is rendered in the template `message.html` it doesn't grab any of the initial data like I would expect. Is there a special trick to get this to work? I've scoured the docs (seems to be lacking examples on generic based class views) and source  but I can't see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 30):

`get_initial()` should just return a dictionary, not be bothered with setting `self.initial`.

Your method should look something like this:

```
def get_initial(self):
    # Get the initial dictionary from the superclass method
    initial = super(YourView, self).get_initial()
    # Copy the dictionary so we don't accidentally change a mutable dict
    initial = initial.copy()
    initial['user'] = self.request.user.pk
       # etc...
    return initial
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but what's the risk of not copying the dictionary?

Comment: @HarryGordon try this:

dict1 = {'a':1,'b':2}

dict2 = dict1

dict2['b']=10

print(dict1)

Comment: looks like all the newlines are lost :(

Comment: Thanks Zhe but I don't understand why the copy is important in this particular case - wouldn't that only be important if the object is still in use elsewhere...?

Comment: @HarryGordon Because it is defined like this [in the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.10.x/django/views/generic/edit.py#L21).

Answer (score 1):

you can use like :

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect

    class PostCreateView(CreateView):
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'slug', 'content', 'category', 'image')
        template_name = "create.html"
        success_url = '/'

        def form_valid(self, form):
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            self.object.user = self.request.user
            self.object.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

**that's work for me**

Answer (score 0):

*(Edited because what you're trying does actually work)*

I ran into the same problem yesterday, but it's working now – I think I was returning an object instead of a dict in `get_initial`.

In terms of fixing your problem, I'm a little suspicious of how much you seem to be doing in `post()` – could you try it with the default (non-overrided) `post()`?

You could also use `pdb` (or print statements) to check the value of `self.get_form_kwargs` make sure that `initial` is being set.