# CBV How to set initial form data from model?

Tags: python, django

I ended up using get_initial as it was mentioned here [How to subclass django's generic CreateView with initial data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666505/how-to-subclass-djangos-generic-createview-with-initial-data)

So my view changed to look like thus:

```
 class VlanFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'vlan_form.html'
    model = Vlan
    form_class = VlanForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = {}
        default_vlan = Vlan.objects.get(pk=1)
        initial['vlan_name'] = default_vlan.vlan_name
        initial['vlan_number'] = default_vlan.vlan_number
        return initial

    def get_success_url(self):
        self.group = get_object_or_404(Group, group=self.kwargs['groupname'])
        # Redirect to vlan list
        return '/ipmgmt/%s/vlans/' % self.group
```

---

I'm looking to be able to have a pre-filled form based off a template of entered data.

So my template is based off first entry in the Vlan table which is 1...

I tried setting the instance on the form_class:

```
form_class = VlanForm(instance=Vlan.objects.get(pk=1))
```

I get a TypeError:

```
'VlanForm' object is not callable
```

Something tells me I am not using the CBV right, how can I set my initial data?
Thanks

My Model:

```
 class Vlan(models.Model):
    vlan_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    vlan_number = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

My Form:

```
class VlanForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vlan
```

My View:

```
class VlanFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'vlan_form.html'
    model = Vlan
    form_class = VlanForm(instance=Vlan.objects.get(pk=1))

    def get_success_url(self):
        self.group = get_object_or_404(Group, group=self.kwargs['groupname'])
        # Redirect to vlan list
        return '/ipmgmt/%s/vlans/' % self.group
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the method `get_form_kwargs` on your view, for example:

```
class YourView(FormView):
    #[...]
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(YourView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['instance'] = Vlan.objects.get(pk=1)
        return kwargs
```

Or you can use an `UpdateView` and implement `get_object`…

Edit: I think I misread your question, as you want to pre-fill the form; so passing `instance=` would not do what you want, as it would also save to that object. For using another object as a template, you could implement the `get_initial` method and return the fields of your object as a `dict`